# Enable bitcode for static framework iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9.2

> ERROR ITMS-90635: "Invalid Mach-O Format. The Mach-O in bundle
>   "APP_NAME.app/Frameworks/WowzaGoCoderSDK.framework" isn’t consistent
>   with the Mach-O in the main bundle. The main bundle Mach-O contains
>   armv7(bitcode) and arm64(bitcode), while the nested bundle Mach-O
>   contains X86_64ALL(machine code). Verify that all of the targets for a
>   platform have a consistent value for the ENABLE_BITCODE build
>   setting."

This library is not install via pods, it's a static library, so how can I enable bitcode WowzaGoCoderSDK framework?